# Use of class variables inside (and outside) of Android threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I created a simple android app to control a robot that has a WiFi access point. The app creates a UDP socket and a thread that listens for messages from the robot. Once a message is received the robots IP address and port are recorded and a flag is set indicating the robot is connected. Once connected the app can send commands to the robot.

When the app receives a message (i.e. socket.receive in UdpServer class returns) I observe the isConnected flag being set to true (running in debugger). But then when I press a button on the app to send a command message to the robot the isConnected flag is now false. Why is there a difference between the value of this variable inside the thread and in another class method?

Source code is shown below:

**MainActivity**

```
package com.test.robotremote;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

UdpServer server = null;

enum Directions
{
  STOP,          
  FORWARD,       
  BACKWARD, 
  LEFT,
  SHARP_LEFT,    
  RIGHT,         
  SHARP_RIGHT        
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Force activity to landscape orientation
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    //Create the UDP server
    server = new UdpServer(49999);

    //Start the RX thread
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(server);
    serverThread.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void sendCommand(Directions cmd){
    byte[] msg = new byte[2];

    //Set direction
    msg[0] = (byte) cmd.ordinal();

    //Set speed
    if(cmd == Directions.STOP)
    {
        msg[1] = 0;         
    }
    else
    {
        msg[1] = 100;
    }

    server.sendUdpMessage(msg, msg.length);     
}

public void handleForwardButton(View view){

    sendCommand(Directions.FORWARD);    
}

public void handleBackwardButton(View view){

    sendCommand(Directions.BACKWARD); 
}

public void handleRightButton(View view){

    sendCommand(Directions.RIGHT); 
}

public void handleLeftButton(View view){

    sendCommand(Directions.LEFT); 
}

public void handleStopButton(View view){

    sendCommand(Directions.STOP); 
}
}
```

**UdpServer**

```
package com.test.robotremote;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;


public class UdpServer implements Runnable {

boolean isRunning     = false;
boolean isConnected   = false;
int localPort         = 0;
int remotePort        = 0;
InetAddress remoteIp;
byte[] rxBuffer       = new byte[1500];
DatagramSocket socket = null;

public UdpServer(int port) {
    localPort = port;       
}   

@Override
public void run() {

    //Run the server receive in the background
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);            

    try 
    {
        //Create an RX packet buffer
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(rxBuffer, rxBuffer.length);

        //Create our servers socket
        socket = new DatagramSocket(localPort);

        isRunning = true;

        while(isRunning) 
        {
            //Wait for received data
            socket.receive(packet);

            isConnected = true;

            //Record sender's IP address and port
            remoteIp   = packet.getAddress();
            remotePort = packet.getPort();
        }

        //Close the socket when thread exits
        if (socket != null) 
        {
            socket.close();
        }
    } 
    catch (Throwable e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
}

public int sendUdpMessage(byte[] msg, int length) {

    try 
    {
        if(isConnected)
        {
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(msg, length, remoteIp, remotePort);           
            socket.send(p);
            return 1;
        }
    } 
    catch (Throwable e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android will kill any process that uses while(true) or recursive threads/tasks which is why your connection breaks. I'd use an Intent Service that starts in the foreground. This is the little icon in your notifications like when you start Pandora. It's Android's best way of executing long running processes.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Point taken. However in this case the thread is still running. I continue to receive messages from the UDP socket within the thread.

Comment: The issue is the "isConnected" variable has a different value in the thread than it does in the sendUdpMessage method.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I have figured out the problem. I wanted this app to always be in landscape orientation and I thought setting the orientation programmatically looked the best. However, there are some unwanted side effects. The issue is the statement below in the apps `OnCreate` method:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

The documentation for `setRequestedOrientation` states this call may *possibly cause the activity to be restarted*. If the manifest file does not explicitly force the orientation to landscape then the activity will be restarted.

If the activity is restarted then `OnCreate` is called multiple times. In this app the `UdpServer` object and receive thread are constructed in the `OnCreate` method. Therefore, the first time `OnCreate` is called a `UdpServer` object is created and the thread is started. The first thread opens the socket. Next when the activity is restarted and `OnCreate` is called for the second time a second `UdpServer` object is created and a second thread is started. Now the second `UdpServer` will not be able to open the socket since the first already opened the socket. Therefore, when messages are received they are received in the first `UdpServer` instance created. However, since the activity was restarted the UI button presses (which call `UdpServer` class methods) are using the second `UdpServer` instance. Hence why the `isConnected` variable was different when viewed in the `UdpServer` receive thread (first instance) versus when a button was pressed on the UI to send a message using the `UdpServer` object (second instance).

The simple (temporary) fix for this is to force the orientation to landscape in the manifest and remove the call to `setRequestedOrientation` from the `OnCreate` method. This still has issues since the Activity can be recreated for other reasons. A more ideal solution is to move the persistent data (i.e. the UDP server object) to the application class which will only be created once for the applications lifetime.